# Div, Grad Curl and all that,Chapter-2 Problem-17: Deriving divergence in cartesian coordinates using a prism as volume infinitesimal

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator

> In the text we obtained the result of of $\nabla \cdot F$ in cartesian coordinates, by integrating over the surface of a small rectangular parallelepiped. As  an example of the fact that this result is independent of the surface, rederive it using the wedge shaped surface as  shown below
>
> [image]

I've been stuck on this problem for quite a bit now, what's throwing me off is that tilted plane area. Anyhow , here is my work so far:

Reference centroid of prism as $(x,y,z)$ and let our vector field be $F(x,y,z) = <F_x,F_y,F_z>$

$$\phi_{S_1 + S_4} =  \frac{ \Delta z \Delta y }{2}\left[ F_x(x+ \frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z) -  F_x(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2},y,z) \right]$$

$$\phi_{S_3} = -\Delta z \Delta x \left[ F_y(x,y - \frac{\Delta y}{2},z)  \right]$$

$$\phi_{S_5}= -\Delta x \Delta y \left[ F_z(x,y,z- \frac{\Delta z}{2})  \right]$$

Now the tricky part is the tilted area of $S_2$, I related it to the flat area of $S_5$ by the formula:

$$ dS' = \frac{dA}{\cos \theta}= \frac{\Delta y \Delta x}{\cos \theta}$$

Which is a formula previously discussed in the book, now for the value of the function on $S_2$, I think it should be the function plus the directional derivative in the direction to the face $\hat{n}$ from the cgeometric center of prism scaled by the distance to that face (l)

$$ \phi_{S_2} = \frac{ \Delta x \Delta y}{\cos \theta} \left[ F(x,y,z) + \nabla F \cdot l \hat{n} \right]$$

The real struggle here is on how to evaluate the gradient of $F$ and dot with the normal because, the calculation here is supposed to be done for an arbitary vector field. One idea I had was to consider the slant height as $\sqrt{\Delta z^2 + \Delta y^2}$ but I ditched that approach because I'd have the square of differentials in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of divergence theorem over a small prism with vertices,
$A \ (x, y, z), B \ (x+\Delta x, y, z), C \ (x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}, y, z + \Delta z), \ D (x, y + \Delta y, z)$,
$E \ (x+\Delta x, y + \Delta y, z)$ and $F \ (x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}, y + \Delta y, z + \Delta z) $

[image]

Vector field $ \vec F = (P, Q, R)$

Outward unit normal vector to surface $ABC$ is $(0, -1, 0)$ and to surface $DEF$ is $(0, 1, 0)$

If centroid of $ABC$ is $(x_g, y, z_g)$ then of $DEF$ is $(x_g, y + \Delta y, z_g)$.

Outward flux through surface $ABC = -Q (x_g, y, z_g) \ dA = - \frac{1}{2} \Delta x \ \Delta z \ Q (x_g, y, z_g)$

Similarly outward flux through surface $DEF = \frac{1}{2} \Delta x \ \Delta z \ Q (x_g, y + \Delta y, z_g)$

Net outward flux through $ABC$ and $DEF$ $= \frac{1}{2} \Delta x \ \Delta y \ \Delta z \  \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \Delta V \tag1$

Similarly outward flux through surface $ABED$,

$ = - \Delta x \ \Delta y \ R (x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z) \tag 2$

To find outward normal vector to surface $ADFC$, we take cross product of $\vec {AC}$ and $\vec {AD}$ in positive z-direction.

$\vec{AC} = (\frac{\Delta x}{2}, 0, \Delta z), \vec{AD} = (0, \Delta y, 0)$

$\vec N = (- \Delta y \ \Delta z, 0, \frac{\Delta x \ \Delta y}{2})$

Outward flux through surface $ADFC$
$= - \Delta y \ \Delta z \ P(x + \frac{\Delta x}{4}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2}) + \frac{\Delta x \ \Delta y}{2} \ R(x + \frac{\Delta x}{4}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2})$

Similarly, outward flux through surface $BCFE$
$= \Delta y \ \Delta z \ P(x + \frac{3 \Delta x}{4}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2}) + \frac{\Delta x \ \Delta y}{2} \ R(x + \frac{3 \Delta x}{4}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2})$

Adding, net flux through $ADFC$ and $BCFE$ can be approximated as,

$ = \Delta x \ \Delta y \ \Delta z \ (\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2}) \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + \Delta x \ \Delta y \ R(x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2})$

$ = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \ \Delta V + \Delta x \ \Delta y \ R(x + \frac{\Delta x}{2}, y + \frac{\Delta y}{2}, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2}) \tag3$

Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get net flux through $ABED, ADFC$ and $BCFE$

$ = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \ \Delta V + \Delta x \ \Delta y \ \frac{\Delta z}{2} \ \frac{\partial R}{\partial z}  = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \ \Delta V + \frac{\partial R}{\partial z} \ \Delta V \tag4$

Finally adding $(1)$ and $(4)$,

Net outward flux through the prism $ = (\nabla \cdot \vec F) \ \Delta V$

Comment: Ohhh beautiful answer Math Lover. The only criticism I have is that you assumed the orientation of prism  and got normal from that. But, I guess that may have been intended because even in the book, the 'cube' which was taken was oriented in a way to simplify calculations.

Comment: Another point is to reduce confusions, I think a picture/ description of how you are orienting the x,y,z axes will help

Comment: Yes to keep the proof manageable, it is important that we orient the region along coordinate axes. In the end, our vector field is any vector field. So if I take a prism that is not oriented along coordinate axes XYZ, we just do change of coordinates so the prism aligns to new coordinates system UVW. If vector field is $(P, Q, R)$, with change of coordinates, say our vector field transforms to $(P_1, Q_1, R_1)$. Now we do this proof in UVW coordinate system for vector field $(P_1, Q_1, R_1)$.